flutter devices not detecting connected iphone device
I am using xcode 14.2 (since my laptop is macOS 12.7 and can't use newer versions) and the iphone is iOS 16.7.8.
This xcode version doesn't technically support this iOS version but it still detects the iPhone, and I have also added the device support files for iOS 16.7 as detailed here: https://github.com/filsv/iOSDeviceSupport.
However flutter devices doesn't detect the iPhone.
Also, xcrun xcdevices list doesn't detect it either, but xcrun xtrace list devices DOES detect it.
I have tried reinstalling xcode several times, restarting mac and iphone.
I also tried running rm -rf ~/dev/flutter/bin/cache and then flutter doctor -v as suggested in another post.
Any ideas?
